# powerShell and regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I have problem to split my text to different variables
For example string like this:

```
oracle\VKAP\.patch_storage\5923165_MAR_6_2007_16_02_56\backup
```

I need to get follow

```
$a = "oracle"
$a1 = "VKAP"
$a2 = ".patch_storage"
$a3 = "5923165_MAR_6_2007_16_02_56"
$a4 = "backup"
```

I will use these variables in my powershell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$a,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4 = "oracle\VKAP\.patch_storage\5923165_MAR_6_2007_16_02_56\backup" -split '\\'
```

or

```
$a,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4 = "oracle\VKAP\.patch_storage\5923165_MAR_6_2007_16_02_56\backup".split('\')
```

in first case you need to escape the `\` char because is a regex and this char have a special meaning in REGEX.

In the second case there is not need to escape because the `.split()` method take as input a `[char]` type value or a `[string]` type value.

Comment: Thank you Very much. It's what I want!